# Cannot retrieve data from MySQL using JSON and put them in a ListView with Fragments

Tags: android, mysql, json, listview, android-fragments

**Source code**

```
public class VendingFragment extends ListFragment {

private String Tag = "VendingFragment";
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

private ListView listView;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray vendingmachine = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vendinglist;

// url to get all products list
MainActivity main = new MainActivity();
private String url_all_vendingmachine = main.getIP()
        + "vendingmachine/get_all_vendingmachine.php";

// products JSONArray

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vending_main, container, false);
    vendinglist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    //listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.allVendingListView);

    listView = getListView();
    new get_all_vendingmachine().execute();

    return view;
}

class get_all_vendingmachine extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        Log.i(Tag, "pDialog");
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        Log.i(Tag, url_all_vendingmachine);
        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method

        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                url_all_vendingmachine, "GET", params);

        // check log cat for response
        Log.i(Tag, json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // Ada record Data (SUCCESS = 1)
                // Getting Array of vendingmachine
                vendingmachine = json.getJSONArray("vendings");

                // looping through All vendingmachine
                for (int i = 0; i < vendingmachine.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = vendingmachine.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString("VMid");
                    String name = c.getString("Name");
                    String address = c.getString("Address");

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put("VMid", id);
                    map.put("Name", name);
                    map.put("Address", address);

                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    vendinglist.add(map);
                }

            } else {
                // failed to create product
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // updating listview
                String[] from = { "name", "address", "id" };                    int[] to = { R.id.vending_name, R.id.vending_address,
                        R.id.vending_id };

                SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(),
                        vendinglist, R.layout.vending_list, from, to);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
    }

}

}
```

I run is and found the error in the logcat once the application launched, no log.i displayed in the logcat

the error message:

```
    03-15 18:21:48.680: W/dalvikvm(13868): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cf12d0)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:386)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.ListFragment.getListView(ListFragment.java:280)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at com.ecnu.vendingmachine.VendingFragment.onCreateView(VendingFragment.java:54)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:828)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1032)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1382)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4456)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
03-15 18:21:48.710: E/AndroidRuntime(13868):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is where i put the listview into a fragment. and now i need to extend it to using viewpager, in the fragment there is a viewpaper and three fragment inside it. people can     horizontal slip it and choose the frament display into the screen.

**each fragment contains its own listview and get data from mysql, can anyone teach me how to coding it... i am very confused about it.**

Comment: don't need `runOnUiThread` on `onPostExecute`, please post logcat error

Comment: why you use the `runOnUiThread` on `onPostExecute`

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan i edit the questions and post the logcat error, it said the "Content view not yet created". Is it something wrong with the "listView = getListView();"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onCreateView` must only return the view that represent the fragment. Other operations on the View should be performed in another callback, your code must be like following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.vending_main, container, false);
}

 @Override 
 public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    vendinglist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.allVendingListView);

    listView = getListView();
    new get_all_vendingmachine().execute();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will read the fragment document again to escape such a error again.

Comment: what's more, about the expand:This is where i put the listview into a fragment. and now i need to expand it to using viewpager, in the fragment there is a viewpaper and three fragment inside it. people can horizontal slip it and choose the frament display into the screen.
each fragment contains its own listview and get data from mysql, can anyone teach me how to coding it... i am very confused about it.